# Centralize text in Rect Using D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I want to centralize my text in the rectangle container that I'm creating using d3.js. and if the text is more than the rectangle can handle then I want to show "some text..."
The Steps that I have taken are :

1. I'm creating a svg container
2. Using that svgcontainer im creating a "g" div
3. And then inside that g container im appending the rectangle and text container to it
4. Below is the code that I have written.

   ```
    window.onload = function() {
    var links = [{
    "source": "Initiate",
    "target": "Dept Approver",
    "status": "completed",
    "type": "process",
    "supersection":false
    }, {
   "source": "Dept Approver",
   "target": "Section Approver",
   "status": "completed",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":false
   }, {
   "source": "Section Approver",
   "target": "Division Approver",
   "status": "completed",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":true
   }, {
   "source": "Division Approver",
   "target": "End",
   "status": "pending",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":false
   }, {
   "source": "Division Approver",
   "target": "End",
   "status": "pending",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":false
   }, {
   "source": "Section Approver",
   "target": "Division Approver",
   "status": "completed",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":true
   }, {
   "source": "Division Approver",
   "target": "End",
   "status": "pending",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":false
   }, {
   "source": "Division Approver",
   "target": "End",
   "status": "pending",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":false
   },{
   "source": "Division Approver",
   "target": "End",
   "status": "pending",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":false
   }
   ];

   if (!links[0]['supersection'])  {
   newFirstElement = {
   "source": "Unknown Section",
   "target": "Dept Approver",
   "status": "completed",
   "type": "process",
   "supersection":true
   }
   links = [newFirstElement].concat(links) 
   }

   var width = 120;
   var barHeight = 20;
   var sample_y=1;
   var sample_x=0
   var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);

   var chart = d3.select(".chart")
   .attr("width", width);

   var supersections=0;
   var max_sections=0;
   var sub_sections=0;

   for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      if (links[i]["supersection"]){
        supersections+=1;
        sub_sections=0;
        }
    else{
        sub_sections+=1;
        if (sub_sections>max_sections){
            max_sections=sub_sections;
            }
        }
    }
   console.log(supersections)
   console.log(sub_sections)


    var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 800)
    .style("background", "#93A1A1");

     var bar = svgContainer.selectAll("g")
     .data(links)
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
    if (d.supersection === true && i==0){
        x=i * width;
        sample_y=1.7;
        return "translate("+i * width +", 0 )";
        }
    if (d.supersection === true && i!=0){
        x=i * width;
        sample_y=1.7;
        sample_x=sample_x+1.7;
        return "translate("+sample_x * width +", 0 )";
        }
    if (d.supersection === false){
        sample_y=sample_y+1;
        return "translate("+sample_x* width+", "+ sample_y  *  barHeight +" )";
        }
    sample_y+=1;
    return "translate("+x+", "+ sample_y*0.5 * barHeight +" )"; });

     bar.append("rect")
     .attr("width", 200)
     .attr("height", function(d) { 
    if (d.supersection === true){
        return "50";
      }
    else{
        return barHeight-1;
      }
    }
     );

     bar.append("text")
     .attr("x", (width+sample_x)/2)
     .attr("y",  function(d) { 
        if (d.supersection === true){
            return barHeight + sample_x /2;
            }
        else{
            return barHeight/2;
            }
      }
    )
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("fill","white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.source; });


    }
   ```

As I'm new to javascript any help is greatly appreciated.

**Current Output**
[image]

Comment: sample_x is the same for every item?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky sample_x I'm changing... since the top elements which have bigger box are super sections and then the below are subsections....and in the links list if you see you will find it follows a pattern like once it encounter the supersection until another supersection is encountered all the section which are found are listed below the first supersection encountered

Comment: if sample_x is different, so the code `attr("x", (width+sample_x)/2)` does not make sense, It should be something like `attr("x", d => getTextX(d))`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky thats true i also thought that ....if you see the current output it is somewhat cetralizing the text in 1st column but not reflecting the in the next columns

Comment: @sachin-raput that's the right direction. If the things don't work, prepare a working snippet and we'll try to fix it there